# How can Aurelia child routing work with a parameter?

Tags: aurelia

I feel as though similar questions have already been asked, but I have been unable to find my answer.

I'm trying to segregate my application by its features. Ideally each feature would be able to setup its own routing as well and Aurelia's child-router functionality seemed to be the perfect fit, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.

The structure of the application is as such:

```
app.ts
app.html
  /lectures
    list.ts
    list.html
    details.ts
    details.html
    index.ts
    index.html
```

I can include any of the other files if needed to answer the question, but have tried to keep the question as compact as possible. The `app.html` and `lectures/index.html` files both only contain `<template><router-outlet></router-outlet></template>`.

I have `app.ts`:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.options.pushState = true;
    config.map([
      {
        moduleId: './public-site/lectures',
        name: 'lectures',
        nav: true,
        route: ['', 'lectures/:id?'],
        title: 'Lectures'
      }
    ]);
  }
}
```

`lecture/index.ts`

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class Index {
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.options.pushState = true;

    config.map([
      { route: '', moduleId: './list' },
      { route: ':id', moduleId: './details' }
    ]);
  }
}
```

and then I have `lectures/details.ts`

```
import { NavigationInstruction, RouteConfig, RoutableComponentActivate } from 'aurelia-router';

export class LectureDetails implements RoutableComponentActivate {
  activate(params: any, routeConfig: RouteConfig, navigationInstruction: NavigationInstruction): Promise<any> {
    debugger;
  }
}
```

and `lecture\list.html`

```
<template>
        <div repeat.for="lecture of lectures" class="grid-body-cell" click.delegate="navigateToLecture(lecture)">
          ${lecture.title}
        </div>
</template>
```

`lecture\list.ts`

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@autoinject()
export class LecturesList {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateToLecture(lecture: {id:number}) {
    this.router.navigate(`#/lectures/${lecture.id}`);
  }
}
```

When the app loads, it correctly navigates and displays the list page, but when I click on any of the lectures in the grid, the url updates to /lectures/1, but my debugger statement never gets hit. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

What seems to be happening is that, while the url gets updated, the router is still directing the application to the list component. Is there a way to get the router to honor and pass on the parameter to the child router?

How do I need to update my setup to get the child router to work with the parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the router element for displaying routed views is called `<router-view>` so your views for child routers should be: `<template><router-view></router-view></template>` - I believe `<router-outlet>` is what you use in Angular 2+ applications for routing. I am making the assumption here you are already doing that if you're seeing things being rendered.

Secondly, you have `config.options.pushState = true` defined on your root router configuration and then inside of your `navigateToLecture` method you are passing in a hash (which is what you would do if you're not using pushState). So Aurelia is removing the hash from the URL (as intended) because you're using pushState and pushState URL's don't need to use the `#` hack.

Thirdly, I would name your routes (and you'll discover why in a moment). Naming your routes allows you to reference them by name and use either `navigateToRoute('routename', {paramsobject})` or `route-href` (which we discuss below).

So, in `lecture/index.ts`, put a `name` property on your routes:

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class Index {
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.options.pushState = true;

    config.map([
      { route: '', name: 'lecture-list', moduleId: './list' },
      { route: ':id', name: 'lecture-detail', moduleId: './details' }
    ]);
  }
}
```

And lastly, instead of having a click event in your view which is calling `router.navigate`, you can use the `route-href` attribute which will allow you to make links work with the router. So, something like the following:

```
<template>
        <div repeat.for="lecture of lectures" class="grid-body-cell">
          <a route-href="route: lecture-detail; params.bind: { id: lecture.id }">${lecture.title}</a>
        </div>
</template>
```

Notice how we are referencing our newly named route by its name, `lecture-detail`? Now Aurelia will come through and parse our link and update the `href` property to go where it needs too.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I finally got it to work last night and will post that as an answer as well. If you have time, I would love it if you could also tell me why my approach isn't as good. I was trying to avoid naming routes because my assumption is that they have to be unique and I didn't want to have to be worried about conflicts. I am coming from Angular and was very pleased with Aurelia at first, but there have been a number of things like this that are making me reconsider.

Comment: Named routes isn't a requirement, just a suggestion and something that I personally do. I follow a naming pattern of prefixing the route name with the name of the view-model to prevent clashes. Don't give up, you'll soon see you made the right choice switching to Aurelia once everything starts to click and you know how things are pieced together. If you ever need help, definitely stop by the public Gitter channel as well (core team members hang out there and answer questions occasionally).

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely give the gitter channel a look. Aurelia seems so elegant, but what I have found so far is that it comes at a big price. Things aren't always intuitive and the docs are lacking. Whatever I have wanted to do there, I have been able to find out how to do relatively easily and while it is clunky often, it is doable. I have posted what worked for me, if you have a moment and could comment on it, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`app.html`

```
<template><router-view></router-view></template>
```

`app.ts`

```
import { Router, RouterConfiguration } from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {
    config.pushState = true;
    config.map([
      {
        moduleId: './lectures/index',
        name: 'lectures',
        nav: true,
        route: ['', 'lectures/*id'],
        title: 'Lectures'
      }
    ]);
  };
}
```

`lectures/index.html`

```
<template><router-view></router-view></template>
```

`lectures/list.html`

```
<template>
        <div repeat.for="lecture of lectures" class="grid-body-cell" click.delegate="navigateToLecture(lecture)">
          ${lecture.title}
        </div>
</template>
```

`lectures/list.ts`

```
import { autoinject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { Router } from 'aurelia-router';

@autoinject()
export class LecturesList {
  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  navigateToLecture(lecture: {id:number}) {
    this.router.navigateToRoute(`lectures`, { id: lecture.id });
  }
}
```

This took me hours of banging my head against the wall and I'm not even sure this will continue to work when I add more routes to the `lectures/index.ts`, but it works for now and allows me to continue on.

Comment: This looks good. It essentially works the same as my answer, except you're using `navigateToRoute` (which I do mention) instead of `route-href`. If you add more routes, everything will work as intended. The only reason a route wouldn't work is if you use the same name multiple times (they have to be unique) or if a routed view-model fails to instantiate because of an inner error preventing it from being composed by Aurelia's router.

Comment: The big change was `'lectures/*id'` in `app.ts`. I was trying `'lectures*path'` and `'lectures/*path'` as that was in the docs, but it seems as though what comes after the * needs to match the parameter name. Still not sure why this works though when I thought the `:<param-name>` was supposed to signify a parameter. It does work, but I'm still very confused and wouldn't be able to explain to or point anyone else in the proper direction. Thanks for your help though.